# When does a .net core exception filter get called after an exception is thrown?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my api I have a standard Controller containing an action, the action calls onto a service which then calls onto client to contact other third party api's.

I'm looking to implement an exception filter something similar to:

```
public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    private readonly IModelMetadataProvider _modelMetadataProvider;

    public CustomExceptionFilterAttribute(
        IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
        IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        _modelMetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (!_hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // do nothing
            return;
        }
        var result = new ViewResult {ViewName = "CustomError"};
        result.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(_modelMetadataProvider,context.ModelState);
        result.ViewData.Add("Exception", context.Exception);
        // TODO: Pass additional detailed data via ViewData
        context.Result = result;
    }
}
```

If my client class for example threw an exception would the filter get called immediately even though my service class which calls the client class had a try catch ready to catch such an exception?

Comment: please provide some code.

Comment: I'll add the exact same code as linked in the question. I thought that was enough.

Comment: im not sure what your asking.

Comment: I dont think it could be any clearer based off the last two lines in the question.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. who is `client`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Per the [documentation you refer to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#exception-filters), the exception filter will only be triggered by unhandled exceptions; if the client exception is handled by the service and isn't rethrown, the exception filter will not fire.

> Exception filters:
>
> - Don't have before and after events.
> - Implement OnException or OnExceptionAsync.
> - Handle **unhandled** exceptions that occur in    controller creation, model binding, action filters, or action    methods.
> - Do not catch exceptions that occur in Resource filters,    Result filters, or MVC Result execution.